# How can I create in Cypher an index that involves 2 primary keys?

Tags: graph, database-design, neo4j, cypher

I am creating a graph in Neo4j and I am starting by creating indexes. One index is linked to one csv file `Product` whose primary key is `productID`, another `Client` with `clientID` as PK and there's another file called `ShoppingCart` which contains `ProductId` and `ClientId` as PK.

Then how can I create an index for `ShoppingCart`? Or is it not needed?

```
CREATE INDEX ON :Product(productID);
CREATE INDEX ON :Client(clientID);
CREATE INDEX ON :ShoppingCart?????
```

Thanks!

Comment: Your shopping cart primary key should be (Client ID, Product ID).  You want to see what a client has in his cart.  You can have a unique index on (Product ID, Client ID) if you want to see who buys bananas.  [Indexes for search performance](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/administration/indexes-for-search-performance/#administration-indexes-create-a-composite-index) gives some examples.

Comment: Hi mate! It didn't allow me to create an index the way is showed in the manual, but doing it like this id did!:      CREATE INDEX ON :ShoppingCart(productID, clientID); why is that?    In the example is showed like:   CREATE INDEX index_name FOR (n:Person)
ON (n.age, n.country)

Comment: It depends on the Neo4j version you are using. In Neo4j 3.x, indices & constraints cannot be named. Starting with 4.x, they have to be named.

Answer (score 0):

With [Neo4j 3.x](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/3.5/schema/index/#schema-index-create-a-composite-index), the syntax is:

```
CREATE INDEX ON :ShoppingCart(productID, clientID)
```

With [Neo4j 4.x](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/administration/indexes-for-search-performance/#administration-indexes-create-a-composite-index), the syntax is:

```
CREATE INDEX shopping_cart_index FOR (n:ShoppingCart) ON (n.productID, n.clientID)
```

Note: at the time of writing, [only Neo4j 3.5.x is supported](https://neo4j.com/developer/kb/neo4j-supported-versions/) in the 3.x series.